# Cannot find the cause of a slow opencart site

Tags: php, performance, opencart

I have an opencart site which Ive been tasked to make faster. It takes approx 3.5 seconds to load, sometimes longer

I can rule out the following causes through trial and error.

- It is not javascript or CSS, in fact I removed everything in header.tpl except for opening the `<head>` and `<body>` tags
- I can be fairly sure it is not an issue with the server. I have other
  sites working perfectly fine, and the admin is also very fast for the
  same site.
- Caching DOES work but its causing a head ache for the client and there are so many products it tends not to be effective. The client needs to clear the cache alot too. To be honest its not getting to the root of the problem either way, its more putting a plaster over it.
- It is happening on all pages, product, category , information
- I have tested just to make sure the issue isnt in the SQL so I change `getProducts()` for instance to `$query = "SELECT * FROM oc_products WHERE id = 100000000000000000";`. As expected it produced an empty array but still a slow load.
- I can confirm it is NOT a slow connection to the database. I ran breakpoints (`die;`) throughout the system process and there is no slow down in connecting to the DB.

Finally, I began to run breakpoints through the controller itself (e.g. category.php). All was fine and fast until right after

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());die;
```

So putting `die;` before this is there is no lag, straight after there is. Keeping mind I have tried this with header.tpl, footer.tpl, column_left.tpl and column_right.tpl cleared of everything expect empty divs, not to mention I emptied the tpl files that would have been loaded, e.g. category.tpl,  I am now out of ideas as to what is causing such a slow load time.

Comment: Did you use chrome to track resources? you can view a timeline with richtclick -> inspect element (new screen shows) click timeline or network -> refresh page

Comment: thanks but i think there's nothing left to track, all my tpl files are empty now however i took your advice and looked at network and refreshed the page, its simply saying content download 3.2 seconds, waiting is 200ms. I dont think that tells me anything new unfortunately only that it is taking that long to get something back from the server

Comment: you can see which script take long to load.

Comment: i cant see how it could be able to tell which script on the server side is taking that long, and all my client side scripts are deleted, its literally a blank empty white page

Comment: you see a list with files they contain script names it is possible they are blocking on the right you see the time they take to load. You can order by time to find long loading scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Download, according to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing) is the time spent downloading the data, meaning your rendered html.

Analyze the size of the overall html document, and see why do you spend that much time **actually downloading** the document.

Regarding caching, I suggest you enable it back on since it will reduce a lot of the processing time.
Learn how to deal with this, ex. [clear the template cache](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=69439) after making changes, priming the cache after doing changes.

If you break or `die` before rendering the content, the response won't be so big therefore you will get a lower "Content Download" time.

Take the following into consideration:
- your network speed
- the size of the document
- enable gzip encoding (this will drastically decrease the size of the response)

Comment: THanks for your help, I tried gzip but to no avail, Im unsure about network speed as every other similar site is completely fine, the size of my document surely cant be big at all? Seeings its literally an empty html page. But that said there's definitely a clue there because If I replace `$this->render()` with something else like `<html></html>` it loads instantly

Comment: you say caching works, use it, and if it causes issues fix those ones instead

Comment: as much as I would go for it myself, unfortunately the client finds it very frustrating, perhaps I should consider a better module

Comment: what part of caching is causing frustration to the client?

Comment: When they make a change they have to clear the page cache at the bottom of the page, also there are 1000s of products and so only the commonly used pages are loading faster. They also tend to clear the entire cache if they make some changes to different part of the site and dont want to have to constantly clear each single page meaing the site gets slow again quite frequently

Comment: Again im open to the notion that there is a better module, Im using this one http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3477&filter_search=page%20cache

Comment: i'm not an opencart expert, but i'm sure a "clear all cache" operation can be added, either using a custom script, either by clearing the cache dir accompanied by a cache priming mechanism. Also note that a new product "doesn't have to be available" immediately after being added. The customer can add all their products, then full clear the cache.

Comment: thanks , my issue is more the fact that there IS a "clear all cache" button. They over use it and so renders the caching process useless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82970/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-adrian).